# Is there a procedure to be followed to add external jars to a custom confluence plugin development environment

Tags: plugins, jar, dependencies, confluence

I added this dependency chunk in my pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>freeway</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have placed my jar file in the folder C:\jarhost\axis-1.0.jar
 And i ran the command

```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile= "C:/jarhost/axis-1.0.jar" -DgroupId=freeway -DartifactId=axis -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And this is the error i get is this

http://imageshack.us/f/580/cmdimage.png

I also stumbled upon this https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/DOC/Adding+JARs+to+an+Application  and tried it too. But it was unable to 'download' dependencies.

What am i missing ?Looking for your help on this.

Thanks
A

Comment: try to add <scope>compile</scope>

Answer (score 0):

You can instal your jar with your plugin by adding dependencie in your pom.xml
in your case i think you need to add scope compile
eg.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

you can read about it [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

and another advice if you start create plugin is best practise is to use Confluence `atlas-cli` ,
 `mvn-instal` not help you in this way.

Also i advice you to read this very usefull [docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Writing+Confluence+Plugins) here you can find a lot's of nice docs which can help you to develop plugins for confluence much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

Angela,

maybe you run into this bug:

> Unfortunately there's a bug in the Atlassian Plugin SDK that prevents
> the atlas-* batch files from correctly interpreting command-line
> parameters that contain an equals sign
>
> The workaround is to call "%ATLAS_HOME%\apache-maven\bin\mvn" instead of "atlas-mvn".

- https://studio.atlassian.com/browse/AMPS-197
- https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/AMPS-353
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/20341/configuring-eclipse-to-use-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk

My solution was the following:

- edit `%ATLAS_HOME%\bin\atlas-mvn.bat`
- locate the line `if "%1"=="" goto loopend` (in my case it was line 69)
- change it to:

  ```
   if `%1`==`` goto loopend
  ```

Hope this solves your problem!